# ANTLR Grammar to parse a Asterisk-delimited input

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am attempting to use ANTLR (v4) to create a parser generator for a asterisk-delimited list encapsulated by START and END markers.

`START**na**na**aa*aa*a*asdfaaa*aaDDFdasa*aaaffdda*aa*aassda*ataaaaaaaaa*a*a*aEND`

Where a normal input string would be something like:

`START*na*na*aa*aa*a*asdfaaa*aaDDFdasa*aaaffdda*aa*aassda*ataaaaaaaaa*a*a*aEND`

I would still need to be able to allow spaces, tabs,  null/empty fields (basically any character except `START, END, *` between the asterisks.

that includes things like `**` `* *` `*asdf fdsa*` `* asdf *`

Here is my grammar so far:

```
parseIt: ENTRY ;

ENTRY : 'START*' FIELD_SET 'END' ;

fragment Delim : '*' ;

fragment Data : (ANY | WS)* ;

fragment FIELD_SET : Data (Delim Data|Delim)* ;
```

I can recognize simple input (like the first example I gave), but am having trouble recognizing tokens that have spaces or special characters between the asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m pretty sure you could handle this with a RegEx and capture groups, but if you really want to use ANTLR…

The following works:

```
grammar asterisks;

parseIt: 'START' dataItem* 'END' EOF;

dataItem: Delim Data?;

Delim : '*' ;

Data : ~[*]+ {!(
       (getText().endsWith("E") && _input.LA(1) == (int) 'N' && _input.LA(2) == (int) 'D') || 
       (getText().endsWith("EN") && _input.LA(1) == (int) 'D') || 
       (getText().endsWith("END")))}?;
```

and gives the following parse tree (for you first input) (click on it to view it full size):

[image: parse tree]

Unfortunately for you, the way the lexer works, a simple lexer rule like `Data : ~[*]+` will preferentially match `aEND` over your `END` implied lexer rule, because the ANTLR lexer uses the rule that matches the longest sequence ion input characters, and `Data : ~[*]+` matches `aEND` while `END` only matches `END` (ANTLR also, doesn't look ahead for token matches).  As a result the rather tortured semantic predicate is the only way to disallow a token that is a stream of characters that ends with `END`.

(Note: Semantic predicates a target-language specific, and this predicate is for Java.  Other targets would require the equivalent int that target language.)

Another approach would be to check if your input endswith(“END”), and then just remove it prior to parsing using this grammar:

```
grammar asterisks;

parseIt: 'START' dataItem* 'END' EOF;

dataItem: Delim Data?;

Delim : '*' ;

Data : ~[*]+;
```

This avoids the `END` token problem by just removing it from the input stream.  Given that it's the very end of the stream, this might be simpler.

Comment: In fact, there is a way to handle any input with a trailing END: `Data: ~[*]+ { !$text.endsWith("END")};`. Using that semantic predicate, you can reject a match when it ends with "END".

Comment: @MikeLischke: I had a feeling I was going to regret "not a way" :).   That said, I wasn't able to use the $text attribute in a lexer semantic predicate, but got this (Data : ~[*]+ {!getText().endsWith("END")}?;) to compile.  However that just results in an "aEN" token followed by a "D" token.  Not sure I'll find time, but maybe can use _input.LA() to look ahead (a quick shot at it didn't work, but I'm out of time right now)

Comment: No worries :-) I didn't test my idea, only remembered having used something similar in the past. Keep in mind that your predicate is triggered for each letter that is scanned.

Comment: OK, it's tortured, but I beat the predicate into submission.  Updating answer.

Comment: @MikeLischke... no comments about how UGLY the solution is... you set me on that path ;).  (Of course, would be really interested in a simpler way)

Comment: I appreciate your help. My requirement unfortunately requires **no** delimiter between the the last data terminal and the end terminal `END`. Wasn't able to get the more complex predicate working.... I end up with `DATA aEND` instead of `DATA a` and `END` as separate tokens.

Comment: You didn't mention what language you are targeting.  Semantic predicates are target-language specific.  That predicate is for Java and does separate ```a``` and ```END```.  I'll append my answer with some more thoughts that might help.